# Get platform specific end of line character in C++/Qt

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform

Is there anything for getting right end-of-line symbol for any platform? I mean, I can use `\n` for Windows and Unix if I want to write EOL to file, but there is also `\r\n` and this would be significant if I'll do searching in binary data.

So, I need something like `Environment.NewLine` in C# and it should be some class and not trick with `#ifdef Q_OS_WIN32...`.

Use case is reading from `QTextStream` all data and split it by new line. Anyway, if `QTextStream` or `QString::split` is smart enough to handle `\n` correctly on any platform, I want to know about thing I asked.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```cpp
QString::split(QRegularExpression{R"-((\r\n?|\n))-"})
```

This uses a C++11 raw string literal to create a regex that matches all three possibilities:

- CR only (Mac)
- CR+LF (Win)
- LF (Unix)

If you can not use C++11, you will have to manually escape the regex:

```
"(\\r\\n?|\\n)"
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: So, you are suggesting to use regex to parse input from text stream? It will have huge performance impact.

Comment: If the data is few enough that you can keep it all in memory without a second thought then it should be the a fair enough solution for recognizing the line ends in a system-agnostic way.

Comment: Of course, if your problem is a bigger one and performance is an issue, you will have to look for more efficient solutions. (Which in turn would be more complex and require magic @demonplus tried to avoid.)

Answer (score 1):

When you are writing a file in text mode, the "\n" character should be reinterpreted as whatever is appropriate for that system. For Windows, that means CRLF (carriage return, line feed), on Unix, it's just LF alone, and the Macintosh standard is a CR by itself.

When you are reading, be ready to end a line at either one of those characters, but if you find a carriage return, check to see if there is a line feed immediately after it, and if there is, consider it part of the same line.

Comment: This is why this questions was asked — I need a class that returns correct EOL, I don't want to check bytes by myself.

Answer (score 0):

I use this bit of code:

```
    const QChar newline(QChar('\n'));
    const QChar cr('\r');
    #ifdef __linux__ 
        const QChar eol = newline);
    #elif _WIN32
        const QString eol = QString(cr) + QString(newline);
    #else
        const QChar eol = cr;
    #endif
```

I have not tested the else branch because I do very little work on systems that aren't either linux or windows (mac for example), so one would have to test that one's self.

The linux, and windows branches work well for me for splitting strings into lines on windows and linux.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using the std::endl

Comment: I guess std::endl is not a variable, it's method that takes ostream as parameter and writes to it end of line. So, I can't use it.